# Determinig the nature of fixed points in a system of N difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

In a system of difference equations...

> $\textbf{x}(n+1) = \textbf{A}\textbf{x}(n) + \textbf{f}$

... I am given the following rules to determine the nature of the fixed point (note that the analogies below refer to continuous equations):

- Case 1) $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are complex, and further
  $\lambda_1 = \overline{\lambda_2}$. In this case, as for continous systems, there is a spiralling effect - towards the fixed point if $|\lambda| < 1$ (stable case), and away from it if $|\lambda| > 1$ (unstable case)
- Case 2) $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are real and greater than 1. The behavior is analogous to an unstable node
- Case 3) $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are real and $0 < \lambda_1, \lambda_2 < 1$. The behavior is analogous to that of a stable node
- Case 4) $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$  are real and  $0<\lambda_1 < 1 < \lambda_2$. The behavior is analogous to that of a saddle point
- Case 5) Either $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ is negative, or both are. There is no analogy with the continuous situation. The solution keeps jumping from one side of the fixed point to the other. If $|\lambda_1| < 1$ and $|\lambda_2| < 1$ then the behavior is stable, and if either $|\lambda_1| > 1$ or $|\lambda_2| > 1$, then it is unstable.

Clearly, the above rules apply to a system of 2 difference equations. How are the above rules written if I **extend** and **generalize** the system of difference equations to any number, say, n?

For example, I've just calculated three eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 6$, $\lambda_2 = -5$ and $\lambda_3 = 3$ for a system of difference equations and am unsure of the nature of the fixed point given that the above rules assume two eigenvalues are derived.

Comment: You really don't want $\textbf{f}$ there, do you? For cases 2 and 3 nothing changes in the sense that you just replace two eigenvalues by all of them (you never say what are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ but it is clear). For cases 1 and 4 you need to start combining behaviors. Really it is better to look at $A^2$ in case 5, much simpler.

Comment: Okay you may drop the $f$.I get what you mean by case 1 and not so much for the others. Not sure what you mean by combining "behaviors" and looking at $A^2$ for case 5